# Selecting columns in R depending on user input

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `col_metadata` in R that goes as:

```
sample | b | c | ... 
____________________
S1     | 1 | 1 | ...
S2     | 1 | 2 | ...
S3     | 2 | 2 | ...
S4     | 3 | 3 | ...
```

I want to make a function that gives me samples that have given values in front of them. For eg.,

```
fun(b,c(1,2))
```

should return

```
S1 S2 S3
```

while

```
fun(c,c(2,3))
```

should return

```
S2 S3 S4
```

and so on. If the column would have been fixed (say, `b`), I could simply do:

```
col_metaData[col_metaData$b %in% inputList,]$sample
```

But since there can be many more columns(hence I can't use if-else), I was looking for a different method to do the same. Can someone please help me do this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Just in case anyone comes looking for an answer, we can use this:

```
col_metaData[col_metaData[,b] %in% inputList,]$sample
```

Notice `[,b]` instead of `$b`.

Comment: or `col_metaData$sample[col_metaData[,b] %in% inputList]`